# Latest update to Craft 3.1.27 crashed server

Tags: updating

I updated the site locally to 3.1.27  (it is working fine) and moved the vendor files, composer.lock and composer.json to the server.

After the update, I went to the admin and clicked on the "finish up" button. On reload the server crashed with the following errors:

18-May-2019 18:42:16 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  require(C:\home\site\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\home\site\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

The File "C:\home\site\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/bootstrap.php" is on the server.

I've reuploaded the vendor files as well as the composer.json and composer.lock. Not sure what else to do. Any ideas?

https://www.untye.com/Before-The-Wall/Liner-Notes

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by using the local database to restore to production. "Finishing up" must have failed to update the db correctly. Fortunately, the local and production databases had been synced before the install failed.